# PHP with ssh2_exec is not executing remote script

Tags: php, linux, shell, ssh

I am new to PHP and trying to create a simple web page, which accepts server name/hostname and execute a shell script on the remote machine. It works fine for simple Linux Command(i.e uname, hostname), but when I am trying to execute shell script which accepts two arguments and hit submit button, nothing is getting executed

```
<?php

$server = $_GET['server'];
$username = “testuser”; 
$password = “password”;
$command  = 'sudo test.sh -a -2018.0220’; 


$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);


ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);


$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);


stream_set_blocking($stream, true);


$output = stream_get_contents($stream);


echo "<pre>{$output}</pre>";
?>

<form action="patching.php" method="GET">
Name: <input type="text" name="server"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I read some earlier post and they suggest use escapeshellarg, I tried that but no luck

```
$var1 = escapeshellarg("-a");
$var2 = escapeshellarg("-2018.0220");

$command  = 'sudo /usr/local/libexec/system_update.sh $var1 $var2';
```

Comment: Your description about how this process is failing is pretty vague. Is your code able to make an ssh connection to the remote system? Is it able to authenticate? Is it failing to invoke sudo? Is it failing to invoke the shell script?

Comment: Thanks, @ken   As I mentioned above normal command like uname and hostname executed properly, it just the issue with executing the script, regarding the error, I am not getting any error in error_log or access_log at apache end, I believe the script is never got executed.

Comment: Check the `auth.log` on the target system. Also, wrap these lines in `if` statements to determine which specific one is failing. Check the sole example at http://php.net/ssh2_auth_password .